# Color Amarillo Menú Hamburguesa bootstrap al hacer clic

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Buen dia.

Sucede que Bootstrap en el menu hamburguesa al hacer clic me deja resaltado el recuadro en color amarillo, pero no encuentro donde esta este color intente buscarlo en la hoja de estilos y no lo encontre.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué nombre de clase tiene?

Comment: Hola Sebastian, tienes que compartir el código (y a ser posible crear un [mcve]) para que podamos ver el problema directamente en la pregunta.

Comment: Ese color amarillo lo define el navegador, puede tener incluso otro color. Por lo general es un `outline` que se añade cuando haces `highlight` en un botón (también es normal verlo en los elementos `input`). Si no añades tu código no podemos brindarte una respuesta adecuada para tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

tenia que aplicar la propiedad Outline-color al button de mi menu, tenias razón es un defecto del navegador.

Comment: No es lo mismo "un defecto" que "por defecto". El propósito de este color en los navegadores es la accesibilidad. Puedes ver más información al respecto en este sitio (en inglés): https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/